# Simple JavaScript to Servlet POST or GET doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

The JavaScript below was adapted from W3Schools. Basically, I just added the URL path to my Servlet in the JS code below.

The Servlet on the server simply returns one of two strings:

```
(1) GET: Hello from Ajax Server!  (**GET**)
(2) POST:Hello from Ajax Server!  (**POST**)
```

The code for the `doGet()` and `doPost()` Servlet methods is to just create a `PrintWriter` from the Response and write a string to it.

---

The JavaScript below does nothing when I run it by clicking the button. I've omitted the URL to the actual server in the JS code below since that's the customer's site.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>AJAX</h2>

    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>


    <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;   
  };

    xhttp.open("GET", "<path_to_server>:8080/AjaxSvr/ajax", true);
    xhttp.send();
   }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```